# Python3: NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is part of a script that causes the error:

```
File "/home/bcramer/workdir-aptaNET/feature_extraction.py", line 28, in <module>
    apt=raw_input('GGGAGWAVIPV')

NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

```py
# ##########################################
##pseAAC encoding
from sys import argv
import string

#20 native amino acids according to the alphabetical order of their single-letter codes
aa_20 = ['A','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','Y']

#count_amino_acids
apt=raw_input('GGGAGWAVIPV')

target=raw_input("SGFRKMAFPSGKVEGCMVQVTCGTTTLNGLWLDDVVY")
```

Below is the original code written by the script author:

```py
#count_amino_acids
apt=raw_input('Please Enter Aptamer Sequence:')

target=raw_input("Please Enter Protein Sequence:")
```

Comment: You're running Python 2 code using Python 3. `raw_input` was renamed to `input` in Python 3.

Comment: OK, code  using 'input' makes the program run. I have new issues and will check what is causing it or change to Python2.7. Thank you. ISSUE CLOSED FOR NOW!

Comment: @Bruno No, you don't want to change to Python 2.7. Python 2 is dead (unsupported) since nearly 2 years and that was announced over 10 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` is a function that's available in Python 2. Python 3 renamed it to `input`. You should either amend your script accordingly, or use a Python version from the 2.x generation (probably the latest 2.7).

Comment: OP, note that Py2 reached EOL on 1 Jan 2020, so you should use Py3 unless you have a good reason not to. https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/